# Problem installing latest vim on ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, vim, gvim

I am trying to install the latest version of vim on Ubuntu 12.10. But when I use this command

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

It gives me such an error
[image]

How to solve this?

Comment: [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](http://askubuntu.com/q/140246/37006)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming vim works, and you would like a newer version. Therefore, my answer deliberately bypasses the method you are trying to use -- sudo apt-get -- which is fine for most things.

However, the fact you have a message "already at the latest level" is telling me you want a newer version.

I suggest you create a scratch directory under ~ after you log in.

1) mkdir vim_install

2) Then [download](http://www.vim.org/download.php#unix) the latest *nix version of vim -- The runtime and source files together: vim-##.tar.bz2 vim-7.3.tar.bz2 -- and unpack it in vim_install. A directory vim73 should be created.

3) Follow the instructions in vim73/README.txt. Almost immediately, you'll be told to read another README that corresponds to your architecture/OS.

4) At some point you'll build and/or distribute as root.

I've done this on several Linux systems we have in production, and downloading vim has never caused a problem for anything else I have installed, because it is built from its sources to run compatibly with your Linux system.

Comment: And this is the solution.... :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running `sudo apt-get install vim-common` before `sudo apt-get install vim`? It looks like it's just missing that dependency; once that's installed I imagine it should work alright.

Comment: Yes. vim-common is installed. Here's the message--

vim-common is already the newest version.

Answer (score 0):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Once that command finishes, then do

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

If the above doesn't work, try

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and try installing VIM again.

Try installing GUI VIM

```
sudo apt-get install vim-gnome
```

Comment: It won't work. Same result again

Comment: Try the additions in my answer.

Comment: Negative result..same output yet.

Comment: Try GUI vim.  See may answer above.

Comment: I think it is the dependency problem vim-athena, vim-gnome, vim-gtk, vim-nox nothing works. Always same error message.

Comment: Have looked at Basharat Sial comment above?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Then, you may need to retry to install vim

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```